# Extract and convert a date from a batch number but the date info does not have the year

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where I have a batch number and I need to validate the the date in the batch number is the same as today's date. I can extract the date out of the batch number but the problem is that the portion of the batch number used to indicate the date is "27.03" or "2703". The year is not shown. How do I go about converting it to a date that I can use to validate? PS. I am using SQL Server 2012

Thank you.

Comment: Is the "2703" portion of the batch number the DDMM part of a date, meaning March 27th?

Comment: Will there ever be batch numbers more than a year old in the database? Also, do the batch numbers have two formats, one with "DD.MM" and one with just "DDMM"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can fully answer the question without more info. You can try to construct the DDMM value using the current date from SQL server, then use that in a where clause.

For example, you can get the ISO Standard date (112 = yyyymmdd) using the following. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(8),getdate(),112)
```

Then from the above YYYYMMDD date, you can get the DDMM value and use it in a where clause something similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @ddmmValue CHAR(6)

SET @ddmmValue='%'+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(8),getdate(),112),5, 2) +
                    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(8),getdate(),112),7, 2) + '%'

select * from MyTest
    where BatchNumber like @ddmmValue
```

This also depends on what the rest of your batch number looks like.

Comment: Thank you. I used a REPLACE statement as follows:

------

SET BatchDate1 = SUBSTRING(Scan,6,4)
SET DateNow1 = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE(),103),'/','')

IF BatchDate1 <> DateNow1

------

And yes, the batch code sometimes is "DDMM" or "DD.MM" but it always has a unique starting character that would tell you what the date format is so I validated for this first and then the date. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just take advantage of what you've got and append the year then use the German date format to convert to a date type. I'm assuming you want your dates to be no later than today's date.

```
select
    case
        when convert(
            date,
            batch_num + '.' + cast(year(current_timestamp) as char(4)),
            104
        ) > cast(current_timestamp as date)
        then dateadd(
            yy,
            -1,
            convert(
                date,
                batch_num + '.' + cast(year(current_timestamp) as char(4)),
                104
            )
        )
        else
            convert(
                date,
                batch_num + '.' + cast(year(current_timestamp) as char(4)),
                104
            )
    end
...
```

Or pretty much the equivalent...

```
select
    dateadd(
        yy, 
        case
            when convert(
                date,
                batch_num + '.' + cast(year(current_timestamp) as char(4)),
                104
            ) > cast(current_timestamp as date)
            then -1
            else 0
        end,
        convert(
            date,
            batch_num + '.' + cast(year(current_timestamp) as char(4)),
            104
        )
    )
```

Or if you're just looking to compare to today's date and handle an optional period between the day and month (after I re-read your question)...

```
where 
    cast(
        date,
        replace(stuff(batch_num, 3, 0, '.'), '..', '.') +
            '.' + cast(year(current_timestamp) as char(4)),
        104
    ) = cast(current_timestamp as date)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes - I just needed to compare to todays date so ideally convert the current date to a working value. But I did use the REPLACE statement as suggested.

------

SET BatchDate1 = SUBSTRING(Scan,6,4)
SET DateNow1 = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE(),103),'/','')

IF BatchDate1 <> DateNow1

------

The batch code always has a unique starting character that would tell you what the date format is so I validated for this first and then the date. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I used a REPLACE statement as follows:

---

SET BatchDate1 = SUBSTRING(Scan,6,4)
SET DateNow1 = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE(),103),'/','')

IF BatchDate1 <> DateNow1

---

And yes, the batch code sometimes is "DDMM" or "DD.MM" but it always has a unique starting character that would tell you what the date format is so I validated for this first and then the date. Thanks again.